# Create new variable based on columns that start with same characters

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a series of variables whose names begin with the same characters:

```
dat<-data.frame(q1.1=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                q1.2=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                q1.3=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                q1.4=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                q1.5=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                q1.6=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                q1.7=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                q1.8=sample(c('answered', NA), 10000, replace=TRUE))
```

I would like to create a new variable based on these variables, in which the observations where all these variables are NA's are coded one way (as "No) and the rest of the observations are coded another way (as "Yes"). I know this can be done in the following way, but I find it far too long-winded (especially when it has to be done several times in the same script):

```
library(tidyverse)
dat<- dat %>% mutate(new_var=ifelse(is.na(q1.1) &
                             is.na(q1.2) &
                             is.na(q1.3)&
                             is.na(q1.4)&
                             is.na(q1.5)&
                             is.na(q1.6)&
                             is.na(q1.7)&
                             is.na(q1.8), 
                           "no",
                           "yes"))
```

Is it possible to instead do this process by writing that if all variables that start with q1 are NA, the new variable should be coded as "no" and if not should be coded as "yes". I have tried to do this method like this `dat<- dat %>% mutate(new_var=ifelse( is.na(contains("q1")),"No","Yes"))`, but get an error.

Comment: Do you want something like: `c("yes", "no")[apply(is.na(dat), 1, all) + 1]` or `c("yes", "no")[(rowSums(!is.na(dat)) == 0) + 1]` ?

Comment: This option doesn't work for me because in the real dataset I am using there are several more columns, so I can't base the new variable I want to create on all the columns in the dataframe. I want the new variable to be based only on the columns that contain a certain string in their name (in this case q1).

Comment: Ok what about: `c("yes", "no")[apply(is.na(dat[startsWith(colnames(dat), "q1")]), 1, all) + 1]` ?

Comment: That does the trick, thank you!